# Using multiple NSSliderCell in a single NSSlider

Tags: cocoa, custom-controls, nsslider

I'd like to create an NSSlider that has three knobs, not just one.  I'm thinking I can subclass NSSliderCell and then override the tracking methods to ensure that one slider cell doesn't pass the one next to it.

That's easy enough to do, but I'm not sure how to tell the NSSlider that it should have all three cells show up, instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use 3 sliders? Remove any text and tick marks to make them small and put them closely to each other. Using a single slider with 3 knobs will give you problems retrieving the slider values.

Comment: Just due to the way the client would like to set the data.  It's basically a lower limit, upper limit, and then another number in-between the other two values.  Using 3 sliders doesn't make it as obvious that there are restrictions on the values.